# Prove $d(x,y)=(x-y)²$ is a metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

How can I prove that $d(x,y)=(x-y)²$ is a metric?
I have proven all properties except the triangle inequality, i.e $d(x,y) \le d(x,z)+d(z,y)$

I have tried to prove it using the fact that $d(x,y)=(x-y)²=(x+z-z-y)²$ but haven't got to anything yet(maybe my algebra is bad).
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately it is *not* a metric, at least on the real line.

Comment: Then, how can I prove that it isn't a metric? Thanks for your help

Comment: It's not a metric: $d(1,3) = 4$ and $d(1,2) + d(2,3) = 1 + 1 = 2$.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample

Comment: You will find this very difficult to prove.. in particular $((x-z) + (z - y))^2 = d(x, z) + d(z, y) - xy -z^2 + xz + yz$ so if $x$ is of large absolute value and $y = 1$ then making $z$ very small violates the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose your'e talking about  a subset of $\Bbb R$ which contains at least three distinct points $x<z<y$, then you'll find out that
$$(y-x)^2>(z-x)^2+(y-z)^2$$
**Pf**

Let $a=y-x>0,b=z-x>0,c=y-z>0$, so $a=b+c$, and 
$$a^2=b^2+c^2+2bc>b^2+c^2$$

Comment: @Crostul it says $d$ isn't a metric